# Experience builder page title set to "Widget"

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder, experience-builder-page

Running into a strange issue on my User Profile page in Experience Builder - somehow the page title is getting set to "Widget" and the builder doesn't have a setting for page title for user detail like it does for other custom pages.

Generated dom:

[image: title html]

Builder settings for page:

[image: builder settings]

It's not getting set in any component's JS as far as I can tell, nor is there site-wide head markup. Anyone ever run into something like this before?

Comment: Got solution for this ?

Comment: @Salesforcedeveloper I did find a solution, I'll post it as an answer here in a bit.

Comment: adding document.title in lightning component did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution for this - the issue stems from a corrupted/mangled translation file. I don't know how this happened to our project as we NEVER changed ours, but the solution was to export the translation file from Builder -> Settings -> Languages [image: screenshot of builder]
It will export a file even if you haven't added or changed any languages yet (Just export the default language). Then open the downloaded file and find and replace all instances of `[Widget]`, save and upload it.